# Assigning to conversion operator fails - C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to cast class `A` into a string as such:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
  std::string data_ = "hello world";

  A() {}

  operator std::string() const {
    return data_;
  }

  template <typename T>
  operator T() const {
    return data_;
  }
};

int main() {
  A();

  // This fails
  // std::string s;
  // s = A();

  std::string s = A(); // This works
  return 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to solve is the part where `s = A();`. It fails during compilation and the compiler tells me there is no '=' assigment operator that assigns `A` into a string.

What is interesting is:

- if its a copy constructor is called (with `std::string s = A();`) the "conversion operator" kicks in and it works (but I want `s = A()` to also work).
- Also if I remove the template method, `s = A();` works.

Can someone please explain what is triggering the different behaviours?

Comment: What compiler are you using? the gcc and clang explain what's going on  (ambiguous overload)

Comment: Works for me when I remove the template. https://wandbox.org/permlink/ThiX9mLrvGsb1XlT. M.M is right that your program is ambiguous.

Comment: @M.M tried on clang and gcc. Yes I'm aware it is ambiguous, but I don't really know when a conversion operator takes precedence over an assignment operator.

Comment: @smac89 I already mentioned in my second bullet point it works if you remove the template method. What is curious is why is the behaviour different when it is introduced.

Comment: write your template as `operator typename std::remove_all_extents<T>::type() const {` - it will compile

Comment: @chutsu the problem is that there are many overloads of `std::string::operator=` and there are multiple possible user-defined conversion sequences;  `string::operator=(string)` <- `A::operator string` is not preferred to `std::operator=(char *)` <- `A::operator char *` for example.  This doesn't arise in the other examples since they do not involve `operator=`

Answer (score 4):

The solution is simple. Make it explicit rather than an implicit conversion:

```
  template <typename T>
  explicit operator T() const {
    return data_;
  }
```

The advantage is now that all four possibilities work:

```
  std::string s;
  s = A();

  std::string s2 = A(); // This works
  std::string s3 = std::string(A());
  std::string s4;
  s4 = std::string(A());
```

Comment: Can you explain why the making the operator explicit resolves the issue? Does this new operator take precedence over the existing non-templated version?

Comment: That result is equivalent to removing `operator T()` entirely, because `operator std::string` is already there in the example. The asker already noted, "if I remove the template method, s = A(); works." Presumably the asker wants a solution that converts to types _other_ than `std::string()`?

Comment: @Lack its not equivalent to removing `operator T()` entirely. If you have a `T` that can be constructed from a `string` it can still explicitly be called

Comment: @user463035818 The result is equivalent in this example. All of the "four possibilities" you show call `operator std::string`; none call `explicit operator T`. If you have an example in which the `explicit` operator does something useful, your answer would be improved by showing it.

Comment: @Lack its not my answer ;). Anyhow, as I understand OP, they do want the `operator std::string` called and the reason it didnt work was the existance of the `operator T`, making `operator T` explicit lets you call `operator string` implicit without ambiguity

Comment: Oh, mixed up the numeric usernames! Sure. I guess the OP is not clear about how they actually use the `operator T`.